# How to say "meeting" in Chinese?

Tags: vocabulary, translation

I would like to create a chat meeting for CL&U and so I thought, why not make the title in Chinese? I was thinking of using the term "meeting" or a similar one.

On my dictionary, for meeting, it lists the word 会议. Is this correct, or are there better terms?

Comment: CL&U? What is that?

Comment: @JamesJiao I think it should be Chinese Language & Usage

Comment: @JamesJiao Like Huang said it's Chinese Language & Usage, following EL&U for English, JL&U for Japanese, FL&U for French, GL&U for German and when it'll enter Beta, IL&U for Italian. :)

Answer (score 3):

会议 is used to refer to meetings generally, which is perfectly fine in this case.

If you want to stress on a particular type of meeting, for example in your case, you could say [讨论会](http://baike.baidu.com/view/2125328.htm), which is an interative meeting where people expression their opinion and communicate their thoughts with others *freely*.

Comment: Interesting! :) I think I'll use the latter, it "sounds" better. I'll wait for other proposals, but I really like yours.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a chat meeting you refer to, you might want to use "座谈会", which means an informal meeting where people gather and have some discussion or chatting on some topic. This is used when the topic is not serious or scientific related.

If you are referring to some serious topics, "讨论会" or "研讨会" is better.